# C: After 10 letters strcat() seems to break

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to write a program encrypts messages using a substitution cipher the key being argv[1] with the plaintext conversion to cyphertext being case sensitive.
Any text with length below 10 lines will work fine however anything above 9 will not.
https://pasteboard.co/tqJoTJcMs07P.png
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Im new to C.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1 || argc > 2 || strlen(argv[1]) != 26)
    {
        printf("INVALID KEY\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i != strlen(argv[1]); i++)
    {
        if  (!(tolower(argv[1][i]) >= 97 && tolower(argv[1][i] <= 122)))
        {
            printf("INVALID KEY\n");
            return 1;
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j != strlen(argv[1]); j++)
            if (argv[1][i] == argv[1][j])
            {
                printf("INVALID KEY\n");
                return 1;
            }
    }

    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    string cyphertext = malloc(strlen(plaintext));
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
    {
        if (plaintext[i] >= 97 && plaintext[i] <= 122)
        {
            char letter = argv[1][plaintext[i] - 97];
            letter = tolower(letter);
            strcat(cyphertext, &letter);
        }

        else if (plaintext[i] >= 65 && plaintext[i] <= 90)
        {
            char letter = argv[1][plaintext[i] - 65];
            letter = toupper(letter);
            strcat(cyphertext, &letter);
        }

        else
        {
            strcat(cyphertext, &plaintext[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", cyphertext);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `string cyphertext = malloc(strlen(plaintext));` needs to be `string cyphertext = malloc(strlen(plaintext) + 1);` to allow for the 0 terminator, and `strcat` expects a pointer to a 0 terminated string, not a pointer to a single character. You would be better off with `cyphertext[i] = letter;`, and you will need to be sure the string is terminated properly.

Comment: Both args to `strcat` need to be valid C strings. The contents of `cyphertext` are unintialised so can contain any random garbage. Set to empty string with `cyphertext[0]=0;`.

Comment: `#include <ctype.h>` is there... You should familiarise yourself with `isalpha()`, `islower()` and `isupper()`... And don't use `strcat()` trying to append a single `char` to a string...

Comment: `strcat(cyphertext, &letter);` You must provide the address of a string, i.e. a nul-terminated character sequence. A single `char` variable does not qualify as string.

Comment: @Hector – Code input/output ist not to be posted as an image.

Answer (score 1):

strcat appends another string, but you seem to be expecting it to append a character.

To make it work using strcat, you could create a short null terminated string to copy in.

```
char cat[2];
cat[0] = letter;
cat[1] = '\0';
strcat(cyphertext, cat);
```

Alternatively you can just use `cyphertext[i] = letter` and remember to null terminate when done.

Comment: The difference in run-time between these two suggestions may be quite significant in the case where the string is long.